# qemu can't attach a readonly drive

Tags: virtualization, qemu

I am running a Ubuntu 19.10 installation (`5.3.0-42-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 28 05:49:40 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`) and am trying to boot a real local Windows 10 installation. The first step (I think) is to get the EFI partition attached. I am trying this: 
`sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -drive file=fat:/boot/efi/,format=raw,readonly`
output:

`qemu-system-x86_64: warning: TCG doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.vmx [bit 5]
qemu-system-x86_64: Initialization of device ide-hd failed: Block node is read-only`

where /boot/efi is the following
`/dev/nvme0n1p2 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this suggestion](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=918950) on the Debian bug mailing list, I was able to get it to work by making the VFAT device read/write:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -drive file=fat:rw:/boot/efi/,format=raw
```

If you need to ensure the files aren't modified, I'm not sure there is a good workaround other than copying to a temporary folder.

Comment: Unfortunately I am starting Windows in quemu, which always writes to the EFI, because everytime I attempt to boot after messing with this, the EFI is unusabale.

Comment: Since this is the solution to this question, I will mark this as solved. I didn't mark it as solved, because I tried to accomplish something else.